# Published https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets redirects to other URL (CSV data)

Tags: csv, google-sheets, redirect, export-to-csv

We auto-publish a Google Docs Spreadsheet (one tab as CSV). Google docs is providing a fixed URL that refers to the CSV. We import this CSV in another tool for product data import.

Suddenly this URL is redirected by Google Spreadsheet. If we go again in "File/Publish To The Internet" we can the same URL for that CSV.

Question: How can get the URL without redirection again?

Error: Source file

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTQsBEmvOwFwxORMqYg2N6LzzYqdqsdDCjxqsdqsdH72gdMCP4xrs1lsN37RO4h1-rjJsQ/pub?gid=501162839&single=true&output=csv doesn't exist (HTTPS : File not found ! (HTTP/1.0 307 Temporary Redirect)). Please check the source file path.

Comment: This threw me off today as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the collection process needs to follow the Location header. Depending how you're getting the CSV this might be simple or a pain. I collect CSVs using `curl` so just adding the `-L` switch is sufficient to make sure the incoming files are the CSV we're looking for instead of the HTML that we were getting without `-L`. Without knowing what utility or process you're using to download the CSV I can't be more specific, unfortunately.

Comment: We passed this to a developer and they are in the right direction with your tip. Thanks!